# django template access multiple dictionaries within loops

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates

I've got 2 dictionaries

```
dictlist = {'Red': {345: 25.0, 123: 67.0, 678: 0, 777: 0}, 'Yellow': {345: 20, 123: 10, 678: 10, 777: 10}, 'Blue': {345: 25.0, 123: 67.0, 678: 0, 777: 0}

dict1 = {345: 4, 123: 4, 678: 3, 777: 1}
```

I want a template that has for each colour:
Code/Percentage(from dictlist)/Totals(from dict1)

So far I've got:

```
    {% for key, val in dictlist.items %}
<h2>{{ key }}</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Percentage</td>
    </tr>

        {% for k,v in val.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ k }}</td>
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
            {% for k in dict1.items %}
            <td>{{ dict1.items.k }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I can't access the matching key from dict1 inside the dictlist for loop... how else can I access a different dictionary inside a loop ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a good usecase to use a template tag:

```
@register.filter
def get_item_from_dict(d, key):
    return d.get(key)
```

and in the template,

You can just do:

{% for dict1_k, dict1_v in dict1.items %}
        {{ dict1_v|get_item_from_dict:k }}
    {% endfor %}

OR

As per the comment, just

```
<td>{{ dict1|get_item_from_dict:k }}</td>
```

Comment: oops, dict1 is actually just a simple dictionary (see edit above). With your filter, I get a "'int' object has no attribute 'get'" error...

Comment: Ok. Then modify it accordingly

Comment: I actually ended up creating the dictionaries in a different way, but thanks anyway